# C++11, `noexcept` specifier, definition versus declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, function-declaration, noexcept

If a declared function has a `noexcept` specificator  (`noexcept`, `noexcept(true)`, `noexcept(false)`, or any other `noexcept(expr)` which evaluates to `true` or `false`), but it's defined in another place, do I need to specify the `noexcept` specifier in the definition again, or only in its forward declaration?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[except.spec]/p4:

> If any declaration of a function has an *exception-specification* that
>   is not a *noexcept-specification* allowing all exceptions, all
>   declarations, including the definition and any explicit
>   specialization, of that function shall have a compatible
>   *exception-specification*.

`noexcept(some-constant-expression-that-evaluates-to-false)` may be omitted. Anything else must be present in all declarations.

Comment: to be sure, noexcept(false) in declaration doesn't have to be present in definition ? What about inheritance and virtual stuff ?